# Ms chart controls for automated report/metrics generation to image, web or win forms?

Tags: mschart, microsoft-chart-controls

Are there reasons to go one way or the other?

`System.Web.UI.DataVisualization` vs. `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization`

I'm building a process for a build server, where it will simply output a chart to an image based on a sql data rows fetched at run-time. I don't have anything vested in either direction, and have experience in both worlds, but none in Ms Charting.

I assume there are good reasons to go either way.

What are the things to consider about going either direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went the WinForms route because it took a long time for our data intensive charts to be generated on the fly. With a service you can have the charts generated slightly ahead of time (5 minute cycle for us) and as a result the webpage loads instantly. Also this means that at most our DB is queried 1 time every five minutes whereas each person who loads the web chart would hit the database individually resulting in a lot more load on the DB.